# Java Swing cannot show FileDialog on mac os 10.15

Tags: java, macos, swing

As descripted in the title.

A demo swing application can show this issue:

The dialog does not show up, and I get the following error in IDEA console:
java[5113:271415] +[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener 'com.apple.view-bridge': Connection interrupted

```java
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame);
fd.setVisible(true);
```

Is this a bug of new macos 10.15? or I have not used FileDialog correctly?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: [FileDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) is AWT and not _Swing_. Did you try [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) ? If you are unfamiliar with it, I recommend [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: Hi guys, this issue has been fixed in the new mac 10.15 beta. How do I operate to close this thread?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that other software has the same problem when trying to search files ([example](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/unable-to-browse-files-macos-catalina.107386/)). You have used the file dialog correctly, so I assume this is a bug in the new macOS.